# Barcode scanning pause and resume on android

Tags: java, android, zxing

I am starting to experience on java in android.
I have 3 EditText on the layout.
I setup a barcode scanning window to scan the barcode.
After getting the first barcode, i pause the scanning and place it on the first EditText View.
Then i resume.

The problem is that after the first scan, the camera does not scan again.
I tried many method, pause then resume and it still does not work.
Can someone help?

The code look like this.

```
private CompoundBarcodeView barcodeView;
private BarcodeCallback callback = new BarcodeCallback() {

    @Override
    public void barcodeResult(BarcodeResult result) {
        String code = null;
        if (result.getText() != null) {
            code = result.getText();

            if (code != null) {
                barcodeView.pause();
                job01 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.jobTicket01);
                if (job01.getText().toString().trim().equals("")) {
                    job01.setText(code);
                    code = null;
                }else {
                    if (job02.getText().toString().trim().equals("")) {
                        job02.setText(code);
                        code = null;
                    } else{
                }
                }
            }
        }
        barcodeView.resume();

    }

    @Override
    public void possibleResultPoints(List<ResultPoint> resultPoints) {
    }
};
```

Thank in advance.
Teddy

Comment: I don't know the answer but I wanna ask you about the barcode library, did you write it or it's open source?

Comment: I can suggest you a workable and trusted library, is that interesting for you?

Comment: Hi, I am using from here. https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded/blob/master/sample/src/main/java/example/zxing/ContinuousCaptureActivity.java

Comment: Hi, It is ok now. I finally decided to create a button to control it.

Comment: I am definitely interested in a workable barcode library for Java. Please provide

Answer (score 1):

I just avoid parsing data from the scan for a few seconds.

I set up 2 values one for the data and another for the timestamp.

```
String barcodeData = "";
Long scanTime = 0L;
        @Override
        public void receiveDetections(Detector.Detections<Barcode> detections) {
            final SparseArray<Barcode> barcodes = detections.getDetectedItems();
            if (barcodes.size() != 0) {
                txtBarcodeValue.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if(barcodeData.equals("") && scanTime.equals(0L)){
                            barcodeData = barcodes.valueAt(0).displayValue;
                            scanTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                            Log.d(TAG, "Barcode" + barcodeData);
                        }else if (!barcodeData.equals(barcodes.valueAt(0).displayValue)){
                            barcodeData = barcodes.valueAt(0).displayValue;
                            scanTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                            Log.d(TAG, "New Barcode Scanned" + barcodeData);

                        }else if (barcodeData.equals(barcodes.valueAt(0).displayValue) && scanTime>(System.currentTimeMillis()-2500)) {
                            //Do Nothing
                            Log.d(TAG, "Barcode  Ignored ---------------" + barcodeData);
                        }else{
                            barcodeData ="";
                            scanTime = 0L;

                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
```